# Dynamic searching and string copying in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I use mailget for a home-made "backup" system, which backs pre-specified files up when receiving a mail containing the string "backup" by using the following search command:

$ `grep -rnw '/path/to/mailbox/' -e "backup"`

I want to extract a mailaddress to a variable $var looking like this whereas the string "Return-Path: " (13 chars), always is static in the beginning of each mail file as following:

> Return-Path:   <someone@domain.com>

In conclusion: When a file containing the string "backup" is detected under a given path, the script is supposed to extract the mailaddress from the regarded file to $var.

Can't get my head around this one, grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi @Simon, please consider rewording this (especially the 3rd and 4th paragraphs). I *think* I understand what you are saying but it's not clear where you mean the string "backup" is coming from (filename? file contents?) and what is meant by "regarded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural mechanism for capturing the output of a command in a variable is "command substitution".  The syntax for a command substitution is `$( <the command> )`; it expands to the standard output of the specified command.

The standard lightweight general tools appropriate for extracting text from a file such as yours are `sed` and `awk`.  You can also use `grep`'s `-l` option to make it emit the *name* of the file wherein it found a match, rather than the match itself.  You might put those together something like this:

```
var=$(sed -n -e '/^Return-Path:/ {s/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/;p;q}' $(grep -rlw '/path/to/mailbox/' -e "backup"))
```

The nested command substitution obtains the names of the files containing the target string; the `sed` command processes those files and extracts (only) the text between the `<` and `>` on the first line starting with "Return-Path:".  It makes some assumptions that render it shorter but less robust; my objective is merely to demonstrate, not to write production-quality code for you.